# django - UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: django, ubuntu

Boa noite galera!
estou com o ubuntu 16.04, tentando voltar pro django, ms quando eu tento iniciar um projeto da esse erro aqui:

> raceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/alekys/Envs/test3/bin/django-admin", line 11, in `<module>`
>   sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
>   File "/home/alekys/Envs/test3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
>   utility.execute()
>   File "/home/alekys/Envs/test3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 345, in execute
>   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>   File "/home/alekys/Envs/test3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
>   self.execute(args, cmd_options)
>   File "/home/alekys/Envs/test3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
>   output = self.handle(args, options)
>   File "/home/alekys/Envs/test3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py", line 33, in handle
>   super(Command, self).handle('project', project_name, target, options)
>   File "/home/alekys/Envs/test3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 162, in handle
>   if new_path.endswith(extensions) or filename in extra_files:
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)

usando virtualenv, baixei o django 1.9.7
alguém que possa me ajudar? já tentei varias coisas que achei pela net, até remover e instalar novamente o python 2.7
desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

Segundo essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36306232/3987358) o que está acontecendo é. No path do seu projeto existe algum caracter que o django não consegue processar.

**Exemplo:**

```
/home/usuario/AndrÀ/projetos/
```

nesse caso o Django não será capaz de processa o caracter `À`. Esse foi o erro similar que foi encontrado. Se possível publique qual é o path que você está tentando criar o projeto.

Como o código que não pode ser decodificado é o 0xc3, você possui um caracter `À`

Comment: esse é o PATH: /home/alekys/Envs/test1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

criei um ambiente virtualenv, usando virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Comment: quando eu digo path, não é a sua variavel de ambiente PATH. Mas sim o caminho que você está tentando criar o novo projeto. Qual é o caminho que você está tentando criar o projeto? E qual  o nome que você está dando ao projeto?

Comment: /home/alekys/Documentos/Programação/Django nome do projeto é test
deve ser a pasta Programação, vou testar em outra pasta.
vlw cara!

Comment: provavelmente é isso. Espero que tenha resolvido